# Using WMI provider WITHOUT installation & GAC registration

Tags: .net, wmi

I want to create a .NET application that will enable my WMI provider as long as the application is running, and disable it on closing.

Is there a way of doing that?

My last resort is install & reinstall on closing.

**Note** that I'm a n00b in the ways of the WMI, so please, you can post even the most trivial and banal answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it will be possible because a WMI provider needs to be registered within WMI (e.g. having an instance of `__InstanceProviderRegistration`). To add to these the .NET installer type [`DefaultManagementInstaller`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.management.instrumentation.defaultmanagementinstaller.aspx) will need to manipulate the WMI configuration data, this requires elevation. (A native application would often use the MOF format file directly, but this still requires copying the file to a protected system folder.)

There appears to be no .NET 4 sample of an in-process WMI provider, but there is one for .NET 3.5: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb885150(VS.90).aspx